# One machine very slow others ok

Tags: windows, wireless-networking

I have Orbi Mesh router and 1 satellite. Internet provider gives 25m down 4 up. Confirmed speeds out of back of modem. Every one of my devices seems to work well except for one machine. It is a dual boot macbook pro running windows 10. Speed tests show 4k down. If I connect to ethernet the speed is fine. When I boot to catalina the wireless is fine but wireless for windows 10 is awful. I suspect a driver but unsure how to proceed.

Comment: For a driver we need the router's exact model.

Comment: rb50 and satellite rs50

Comment: Why two of them?

Comment: why not, i'm not going to discuss design

Answer (score 0):

Checked router and satellite, everything working normally. Checked driver on Broadcom driver and updated without improvement. Checked network throughput and it was definitely the network adapter -- probably unable to negotiate the protocols correctly -- so I rolled back driver to previous version and that fixed the problem.